# HSSFCellStyle error using Apache poi with android

Tags: java, android, apache-poi

I have been searching for a week now and still have no clue what lacks in my code. I was wondering if any of you guys knows why my HSSFCellstyle Syntaxes won't be recognized by android studio.

```
public boolean exportToExcel(final Context context, final String fileName){
    if (!isExternalStorageAvailable() || isExternalStorageReadOnly()) {
        Log.e("External Storage", "Storage not available or read only");
        return false;
    }

    resultExcelArrayList = new ArrayList<>();

    success = false;

    String sheetName = "Sheet1";

    wb = new HSSFWorkbook();
    sheet = wb.createSheet(sheetName) ;

    HSSFCellStyle borderBottom = wb.createCellStyle();
    borderBottom.setBorderBottom(HSSFCellStyle.BORDER_MEDIUM);


    HSSFRow row = sheet.createRow(0);
    HSSFCell cell1 = row.createCell(0);
    HSSFCell cell2 = row.createCell(2);
    cell1.setCellValue("KanziApp");
    cell2.setCellValue(new Date());

    HSSFRow row2 = sheet.createRow(2);
    HSSFCell cell3 = row2.createCell(0);
    HSSFCell cell4 = row2.createCell(1);
    HSSFCell cell5 = row2.createCell(2);
    cell3.setCellValue("Scan");
    cell4.setCellValue("Class");
    cell5.setCellValue("Result");

    if (mScansReference.child(mUserID).child("current_scan").child("scans") != null){
        mScansReference.child(mUserID).child("current_scan").child("scans")
                .addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        int count = 3;
                        for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                            String detail = snapshot.child("detail").getValue().toString();
                            String result = snapshot.child("result").getValue().toString();

                            HSSFRow row = sheet.createRow(count);
                            HSSFCell cell1 = row.createCell(0);
                            HSSFCell cell2 = row.createCell(1);
                            HSSFCell cell3 = row.createCell(2);
                            cell1.setCellValue(snapshot.getValue().toString());
                            cell2.setCellValue(detail);
                            cell3.setCellValue(result);

                            resultExcelArrayList.add(new Result(detail, result));

                            count++;
                        }

                        File file = new File(context.getExternalFilesDir(null), fileName);
                        FileOutputStream os = null;

                        try {
                            os = new FileOutputStream(file);
                            wb.write(os);
                            Log.w("FileUtils", "Writing file" + file);
                            success = true;
                            sendEmail(getBaseContext(), "textFile.xls");
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            Log.w("FileUtils", "Error writing " + file, e);
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            Log.w("FileUtils", "Failed to save file", e);
                        } finally {
                            try {
                                if (null != os)
                                    os.close();
                            } catch (Exception ex) {
                            }
                        }

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                    }
                });
    }

    return success;
}
```

In this part of my code;

```
HSSFCellStyle borderBottom = wb.createCellStyle();
borderBottom.setBorderBottom(HSSFCellStyle.BORDER_MEDIUM);
```

In this case "BORDER_MEDIUM" is not recognized, and will give an error when I build. Anyone who has a clue what I am missing?

Comment: This depends on what you are exactly using and on what `apache poi` version this is set up. Newest `apache poi` version needs [HSSFCellStyle.setBorderBottom](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/hssf/usermodel/HSSFCellStyle.html#setBorderBottom-org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.BorderStyle-) having a [BorderStyle](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/BorderStyle.html) as the parameter.

Comment: I edited your solution to a community wiki answer.

Answer (score 0):

*Solution by OP.*

Commented by Axel Richter:

> Newest `apache poi` version needs [HSSFCellStyle.setBorderBottom](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/hssf/usermodel/HSSFCellStyle.html#setBorderBottom-org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.BorderStyle-) having a [BorderStyle](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/BorderStyle.html) as the parameter.

Solved by updating the parameters from:

```
borderBottom.setBorderBottom(HSSFCellStyle.BORDER_MEDIUM);
```

To:

```
borderBottom.setBorderBottom(BorderStyle.BORDER_MEDIUM);
```